# Changing IE Document Mode via Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fancybox, bookmarklet, quirks-mode

I am currently in development of a bookmarklet that triggers a fancybox Iframe when an image is clicked on a website. This bookmarklet works great in all browsers except IE 9's Quirks Mode. In fact, it not only screws up the rendering of items on the screen, but items within the Iframe as well. I'm looking for a solution to force IE into standards mode. Especially on pages where there is no Doctype declared. In fact a static image on a page is our current test for the bookmarklet.

Success equals - 
1. Launching the bookmarklet on a Quirks Mode page
2. Having the fancybox iframe load in the proper location on screen with proper rendering

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: I am afraid that fancybox won't work (properly in IE) if the document has not a proper `DOCTYPE`

Comment: could you provide part of the code that works in the other browsers but not in Quirk mode?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a solution to force IE into standards mode.

I'm pretty sure there is no way. Changing the rendering mode with Javascript just wouldn't be a scenario that anyone would consider necessary or beneficial; your use-case is just too obscure.

> Success equals - 1. Launching the bookmarklet on a Quirks Mode page 2. Having the fancybox iframe load in the proper location on screen with proper rendering

If fancybox won't work, then try out alternative solutions: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20lightbox